# Html email signature not in order with Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I exported my email signature image for the web via Photoshop and uploaded all the image content to Google Drive.

I included them into Html file.

I have opened the signature in browser and it looks great, but when I copy it in my Outlook signature box it looks messy.

**Outlook image**

[image: Outlook image]

And my part of the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em; }
img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <table id="Table_01" width="331" height="151" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="11">
                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1jgTvqTAsp" width="331" height="65" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1TV37hTkDyL0JdPU" width="46" height="10" alt=""></td>
           ...
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

I can't figure out what the problem could be. Has anyone had the same issue?

Comment: We can't figure out the issue either unless you post a code sample.

Comment: Sorry, here is the part. @gwally

Comment: if you're relying on the embedded styles (in head), they'll probably be removed. Push them inline (style=)

Comment: I have done that. Still, no progress? @Nathan

Comment: Your `colspan` values don't match. Removing it might be a good idea as both rows have 1 column each and yes keep the CSS inline.